# Converting MSSQL to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database-migration

Hye, I'm trying to convert a MSSQL query over to MYSQL and it's causing me issues. This is beyond my current comfort zone. Below is my current query.

```
WITH n AS ( 
  SELECT n from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(n) /* create a numbers table with 10 rows */ 
) 
, d AS ( /* Create a table with a row for each day in the date range */ 
         /* Use cross join to increase the rows in this table and then use top() to only return the rows we need */ 
   SELECT top (datediff(day, '2017-07-04', '2018-03-02')+1) 
   SessionDate = convert(datetime,dateadd(day,row_number() over(order by (select 1))-1,'2017-07-04')) 
   FROM n AS ten 
   CROSS JOIN n AS hundred /* cross join the numbers table to create 100 rows */ 
   CROSS JOIN n AS thousand /* cross join the numbers table to create 1,000 rows */ 
   CROSS JOIN n AS tenK /* cross join the numbers table to create 10,000 rows */ 
   CROSS JOIN n AS hundredK /* cross join the numbers table to create 100,000 rows */ 
   ORDER BY SessionDate 
) 
, h as ( /* add time ranges to date table */ 
    SELECT SessionDate, StartDateTime = dateadd(hour,v.s,SessionDate), EndDateTime = dateadd(hour,v.e,SessionDate), v.point 
    FROM d 
    CROSS APPLY (values 
       (0,12,'morning') 
       ,(12,17,'afternoon') 
       ,(17,24,'evening') 
    ) 
    v (s,e,point) 
) 
SELECT *
FROM h
```

It's using a numbers table and splitting out the dates into different time frames. Below is an example of the result set

```
SessionDate             | StartDateTime           | EndDateTime             | Point
2017-07-04 00:00:00.000 | 2017-07-04 00:00:00.000 | 2017-07-04 12:00:00.000 | morning
2017-07-04 00:00:00.000 | 2017-07-04 12:00:00.000 | 2017-07-04 17:00:00.000 | afternoon
2017-07-04 00:00:00.000 | 2017-07-04 17:00:00.000 | 2017-07-05 00:00:00.000 | evening
2017-07-05 00:00:00.000 | 2017-07-05 00:00:00.000 | 2017-07-05 12:00:00.000 | morning
2017-07-05 00:00:00.000 | 2017-07-05 12:00:00.000 | 2017-07-05 17:00:00.000 | afternoon
2017-07-05 00:00:00.000 | 2017-07-05 17:00:00.000 | 2017-07-06 00:00:00.000 | evening
2017-07-06 00:00:00.000 | 2017-07-06 00:00:00.000 | 2017-07-06 12:00:00.000 | morning
2017-07-06 00:00:00.000 | 2017-07-06 12:00:00.000 | 2017-07-06 17:00:00.000 | afternoon
2017-07-06 00:00:00.000 | 2017-07-06 17:00:00.000 | 2017-07-07 00:00:00.000 | evening
```

Comment: You lost. MySQL is rather ... restricted when it comes to SQL features. It has no windowing, ranking or analytic functions. Ranking is typically emulated using rather ugly hacks or undocumented features. For example, row numbers can be generated by incrementing a ... variable in the select clause. `...,@rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank`

Comment: The current version of MySql does not support Windowing Functions (`row_number()`), CTEs, or lateral joins (`APPLY`), all of which are used here. You'll have to completely re-write this query, if it's even possible. The CTE thing is getting fixed for the next full MySql release, but windowing functions and lateral joins are still awol, along with full join, materialized views, etc. IMO, MySql isn't really a "modern" relational DB, and hasn't been for over a decade. If you want to go free/OSS, Postgresql would likely have been a much better choice.

Comment: Good luck.  Most of the features used in this query don't exist in MySQL.  You might as well create your query from scratch rather than trying to convert this into MySQL query.  No `CTE`, No `CROSS JOIN`, No `OVER()`, No `CROSS APPLY`.

Comment: "MySQL query. No CTE, No CROSS JOIN, No OVER(), No CROSS APPLY" MySQL supports CROSS JOIN @Eric

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think the hacks are rather beautiful

Comment: @Strawberry perhaps you haven't considered the implications - it's impossible to use ranking in a subquery. The query has to be converted into a serial loop, essentially a cursor. The query can't be parallelized. It's impossible to calculate other types of ranking or windowing without cursors. Hacks like allowing non-group columns in a SELECT aren't just unsupported but result in huge performance penalties in newer editions. When you start considering running sums and averages things become a lot harder

Comment: @user2634794 you should create a numbers and possibly a calendar table and use them to simplify the query. Your code doesn't use a numbers table, it uses a CTE that returns a sequence of numbers. Even in SQL Server, it would be a lot faster to store the numbers in an actual indexed table.

Comment: @user2634794 You could also create a *time* table that matches hours to morning, afternoon etc. After that you'll only have to create the cartesian product between the calendar and time table for the date range you want. This will result in a much simpler and faster query

Answer (score 2):

The query is too clever - it uses a CTE to generate a sequence of numbers instead of a calendar table, it uses CROSS APPLY to generate hours instead of using a lookup table for hours and names. The resulting execution plan will be *bad*.

A very simple calendar table and a 'Sessions` table will allow you to create a far simpler T-SQL query, eg :

```
CREATE TABLE Calendar (Date date primary key not null)
GO
--Omit code to fill the calendar
CREATE TABLE Sessions (StartTime int,EndTime int, Name nvarchar(20))
GO
insert into Sessions (StartTime,EndTime,Name)
VALUES
(0,12,'morning'),
(12,17,'afternoon'),
(17,24,'evening') 


select Date as SessionDate,
    dateadd(hour,StartTime,Date) as StartTime,
    dateadd(hour,EndTime,Date) as EndTimeTime,
    Name
from Calendar,Sessions
where Date between @startDate and @endDate
```

The range query will be very fast because the `Date` column is indexed. The execution plan will simply return all applicable date rows and combine them with the Session rows.

This can be easily converted to MySQL's dialect, eg by using DATE_ADD instead of DATEADD